# Issues with Exported Crystal Report to Word Document

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, reporting

I am having a minor issue playing with my exported Crystal Report, I can generate the reports just fine on our website, however when I attempt to export them to Word documents I don't quite get a document I can do much with.

i.e.:

1. I can't position the generated text anywhere in the document, it is almost 'frozen' in place.  I would expect if I moved the cursor above the report text and pressed Enter a bunch of times I could remove the report down the page, however it just won't budge
2. All the text seems to be in its own box and I can't move it around or do anything with it.

Any thoughts?  My expectation would be once it is exported to Word I could play with it like a Word document, move the text down the page, edit the document, do something with it.

Thanks!

btw, this question is similar to the one posted here, but this one wasn't tagged properly and I don't have enough karma to fix it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434381/word-formatting-not-intact-when-exported-from-crystal-reoport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't do much about it. Crystal Reports is very much orientated towards putting data in fixed positions on pages, so when it exports to Word it puts its data into text boxes because that's a similar thing that Word offers. You could make the Crystal Report page consists of a giant text field and using spaces and newlines to get the data into the right place, which will probably then give you a giant textbox in Word.